# How to test my jQuery plugin with Gulp, Jasmine and NodeJS?

Tags: jquery, gulp, jasmine

I created a [simple jQuery plugin](https://github.com/yegor256/colorizejs/blob/master/gulpfile.js), which modifies the HTML according to some simple rules, using jQuery. Now I need to test that it works. I use Gulp for build automation. I decided to use Jasmine for unit testing. My question is how do I run my plugin from the `test.js` and validate the result? I have node.js installed at the build server.

Comment: Do you need something like karma test runner?

Comment: @XavitojCheema I'm not sure what I need and how it should be used, that's why asking here...

Comment: You can simply open your spec.html file in your browser, that should be enough to run your tests. You can use karma test runner with gulp too

Comment: @XavitojCheema in my browser? :) Will Travis also open it in my browser?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Solution**

Use `jsdom` to emulate a browser within your `Jasmine` unit tests.

**Details**

[`jsdom`](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom#--------jsdom) is "a pure-JavaScript implementation of many web standards...for use with Node.js...to emulate enough of a subset of a web browser to be useful for testing and scraping real-world web applications".

`jsdom` has become the de facto standard for emulating a browser within `Node.js`.  It has [over 2 million weekly npm downloads](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom) and, among other things,  is included automatically as the [default test environment in `Jest`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html#testenvironment-string).

`jsdom` provides the `window` needed to initialize jQuery, load a jQuery plugin, and unit test it using `Jasmine` from within `Node.js` as if it were running in a browser:

---

colorize-spec.js

```
const { JSDOM } = require('jsdom');
const { window } = new JSDOM();
global.$ = require('jquery')(window);
require('../src/colorize');

describe('colorize', () => {

  const div = $('<div/>');
  const settings = { 30: 'highest', 20: 'middle', 10: 'lowest' };

  it('should set the applicable class', () => {
    div.text('35').colorize(settings);
    expect(div.attr('class')).toBe('highest');

    div.text('25').colorize(settings);
    expect(div.attr('class')).toBe('middle');

    div.text('15').colorize(settings);
    expect(div.attr('class')).toBe('lowest');

    div.text('5').colorize(settings);
    expect(div.attr('class')).toBe('');
  });

});
```

---

I created a [pull request](https://github.com/yegor256/colorizejs/pull/2) that includes `jsdom` as a dev dependency, bumps `node` to v8 in `Travis CI`, and includes this initial unit test.  It passes the build checks (including this unit test) and is ready to merge.

Comment: @yegor256 you can add `e2e` tests that load headless browsers, etc. to verify that the plugin plays nicely in specific browsers and environments, but your question is for unit testing the pure functionality of the code and for that nothing is cleaner and faster than using something like `jsdom` to test the code in-process within `Jasmine`.

Comment: @yegor256 glad it worked for you!    feedback for next time: mark as accepted a bit quicker so the bounty doesn't expire 

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to use the [`gulp-jasmine-browser` npm plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-jasmine-browser). This will allow you to run your tests in a normal browser, or headless browser. The gulp task you need to create is something like this:

```
let gulp = require('gulp');
let jasmineBrowser = require('gulp-jasmine-browser');

gulp.task('jasmine', () => {
  return gulp.src(['src/**/*.js', 'spec/**/*_spec.js'])
    .pipe(jasmineBrowser.specRunner())
    .pipe(jasmineBrowser.server({port: 8888}));
});
```

Or, if you want to run in a headless server, change the last line to this:

```
    .pipe(jasmineBrowser.headless({driver: 'chrome'}));
```

Answer (score 1):

Testing it with gulp and Karma..
Assuming you have install all the gulp files and their dependencies. Make your gulp task

Generate your karma conf file..

```
karma init karma.conf.js

gulp.task('tests', function (done) {
   return karma.start({
   configFile: __dirname + '/karma.conf.js',
   singleRun: false
  }, done);
});

gulp.task('default', ['tests']);
```

Edit conf file as per your file path

```
files: [
   '<PATH-TO-TESTS>/*.js', '<PATH-TO-JQUERY>/jquery.js', '<PATH-TO-PLUGIN>/<PLUGIN-NAME>.js',
 {
   pattern:  '<PATH-TO-TESTS>/*.html',
   watched:  true,
   served:   true,
   included: false
 }
]
```

Write your test js

```
describe('myPlugin Initialisation', function() {

var el, myPlugin;

beforeEach(function(){
    jasmine.getFixtures().fixturesPath = 'base/Tests';
    loadFixtures('Template.html');
    el = $('#myPlugin-Test');
    myPlugin = el.myPlugin().data('myPlugin');
});
});
```

The tests themselves are also a simple structure and jasmine users will be familiar once again:

```
 `it('Should add the class "myPlugin" to the element', function() {
     expect(el.hasClass('myPlugin')).toBe(true);
 });`
```

All you need to do now is run:

```
 `gulp tests`
```

you can refer this url https://earthware.co.uk/blog/using-gulp-and-karma-to-test-a-jquery-plugin/