# Jest - DOM related and across JS files Unit Testing

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, puppeteer

I am using [Jest](https://jestjs.io/) for Unit Testing. Added [jest-puppeteer](https://github.com/smooth-code/jest-puppeteer) and [rewire](https://github.com/jhnns/rewire) in it. The problem is when I am trying to call `sayHello()` using the below the code, `$button` variable is undefined and throws error in `main.js`. And if I call `someFunctionFromAnotherJS()`, that is also throwing error. This will return error anyway as I don't know how to write unit tests for DOM related and for across JS files. Please note I also need to use all the global variables loaded in the browser in JS files.

Please look at the below code and tell me how can I achieve this.

**tests/main.test.js**

```
var rewire = require('rewire');
var main = rewire('../main');
var sayHello = main.__get__('sayHello');

describe('Testing', () => {
  beforeAll(async () => {
    await page.goto('https://***.**.com/**');
  });

  it('should test page', async () => {
    await page.type('#lid', '*****@gmail.com');
    await page.type('#pwd', '*****');
    await page.click('#signin_submit');
    var dimensions = await page.evaluate(() => {
      return {
        width: document.documentElement.clientWidth,
        height: document.documentElement.clientHeight,
        deviceScaleFactor: window.devicePixelRatio
      };
    });

    await page.goto('https://***.**.com/**', {timeout: 30000, waitUntil: 'load'});
    await page.goto('https://***.**.com/**', {timeout: 30000, waitUntil: 'load'});
    var evaluatedPage = await page.evaluate(() => {
      return {
        isFreeUser: window.isFreeUser
      };
    });
    await page.screenshot({path: 'screenshot.png'});
    console.log('Evaluated Page:', evaluatedPage);
    expect(evaluatedPage.isFreeUser).to.equal(false);

    sayHello();
  });
});
```

**main.js**

```
var $button = $('#myButton');

function sayHello() {
    $button.text('Hello!');
    return someFunctionFromAnotherJS();
}
```

**another.js**

```
function someFunctionFromAnotherJS() {
    return 'hello';
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To debug this problem, you can console.log(sayHello) and see what is actually in there. If sayhello itself is a proper function, then proceed,

It seems `main.js` is a script that is supposed to run on the browser. If that's the case you should run it on the browser and not on the nodeJS context.

Instead of `sayHello();`, you can try,

```
await page.evaluate(sayHello)
```

That way it will execute on the browsers context.

EDIT: jest-puppeteer is just an extension of jest help you testing various little pieces. You can write the tests seperately. But if you want to run and test DOM functions then you have to use something that can run that DOM function. That is a fact.

I am not sure why you are trying to run a jQuery code (which depends on browsers `window` and `document`) on nodeJS environment.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51904256/6161265), you will need to emulate the DOM somehow. So `Puppeteer`, `jsdom` and others helps you do that. Reference answer:

If you really wanna keep everything seperate and do not want to use `puppeteer` (which I really don't understand why would you want to do that), then you can try few combinations of following to see what works best for you, but remember you are trying to reinvent what is already there,

- [jsdom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom)
- [jquery](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery)
- [cheerio](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio)

Comment: Can't we write unit tests for `sayHello()` without using [jest-puppeteer](https://github.com/smooth-code/jest-puppeteer) library?

Comment: The global variables loaded initially from JSP is also used in JS functions. Can you suggest some source code links for writing unit tests for getting global variables, for handling function calls across JS files and for DOM related? I don't know whether mocking everything is the best solution because we always have to test our code written in our JS files right

Comment: You can reinvent the wheel and create your own version similar to jest-puppeteer if you want. The goal here is to test functions that works with DOM of a live browser, right? In that case you do need a live browser. There might be ways like jsdom, cheerio etc. But that'll be like heading for disadvantage.

Comment: Using both jest-puppeteer and jest seems to be merging automation testing and unit testing. Is this the only best way to write complete unit tests for my code?

Comment: Check my updated answer. You need DOM to test DOM things, that's fact. NodeJS cannot make a dom for you out of nowhere. ;)